# Is there a way to know table alias before use it in @Formula annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, alias

```
@Formula(customer_table_alias + ".count + 1")
private int count;
```

I need to know which alias Hibernate will set for the customer table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to use subselect

```
@Formula("(select count+1 as new_count from customer_table ct where ct.id=current_id)")
private int count;
```

where `current_id` is id column of the entity